# Comments -> link to node

Tags: nodes, comments

i have a content type which display some text image and comments count, in my View module i need to rewrite this comment count to link on this node. How to do it?
I though i should create field with nid but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the "Node ID (nid)" field
2. Add the "Comment count" field -> Configure field -> Rewrite results -> Output this field as link -> in the "Link path" enter: node/[nid]

You can hide the nid field as you probably don't need it.

Make sure the comment count is coming after the nid. You can just reorder them.